# weak in swift disappears in objective-C header file

Tags: objective-c, swift

So we have a swift library, and we use it in Objective-C based project.

In swift, there is a class like this:

```
/// Base class for all axes
@objc(ChartAxisBase)
open class AxisBase: ComponentBase
{
    public override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    /// Custom formatter that is used instead of the auto-formatter if set
    weak fileprivate var _axisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?


    /// Sets the formatter to be used for formatting the axis labels.
    /// If no formatter is set, the chart will automatically determine a reasonable formatting (concerning decimals) for all the values that are drawn inside the chart.
    /// Use `nil` to use the formatter calculated by the chart.
    open var valueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?
    {
        get
        {
            if _axisValueFormatter == nil ||
                (_axisValueFormatter is DefaultAxisValueFormatter &&
                    (_axisValueFormatter as! DefaultAxisValueFormatter).hasAutoDecimals &&
                    (_axisValueFormatter as! DefaultAxisValueFormatter).decimals != decimals)
            {
                let df = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals)
                _axisValueFormatter = df
                NSLog("found nil vf, assigning to \(_axisValueFormatter)")
            }
            NSLog("returning \(_axisValueFormatter)")
            return _axisValueFormatter
        }
        set
        {
            _axisValueFormatter = newValue //?? DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

As you see, there is a private var declared as weak:

> weak fileprivate var _axisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?

and there is a getter and setter for `valueFormatter`.

However, latest Xcode 8.2.1 will generate a Objective-C header for `valueFormatter` like:

> @property (nonatomic, strong) id  _Nullable valueFormatter;

As you can see, it's strong, and I can' find any `_axisValueFormatter` in the header file as well.

Is this expected? How can I make it right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `valueFormatter` defined as strong property. `_axisValueFormatter` is defined as `fileprivate` therefore cannot be accessed from outside. So everything as expected.

To conclude:

1. `_axisValueFormatter` will remain weak.
2. Storage modifier for `valueFormatter` is irrelevant since internal implementation relies on weak private property `_axisValueFormatter`.

You claim that `valueFormatter` is strong but then you back it with `weak` property that can turn nil anytime. This is a property with side effect. I would suggest to avoid that and simply mark `valueFormatter` as `weak` to adjust the expectations for developers that will use your class.

Take a look at documentation regarding weak and strong references:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48

Comment: Then, `_axisValueFormatter` is weak in swift, how about in objective-c? Although the open property axisValueFormatter seems like strong, but the underlying `_axisValueFormatter` is weak. Will it work just like weak property in objective-c?

Comment: I am a little confused then, if I can specify weak for property valueFormatter, then, about the private var, if I declare _axisValueFormatter NOT as weak, what would happen?

Comment: @Wingzero it will basically act as strong property. In your example valueFormatter stores value in private _axisValueFormatter so technically you can assume that valueFormatter is a proxy to _axisValueFormatter. Is there a good reason to use weak _axisValueFormatter? Because weak doesn't retain the value.

Comment: no, we decides hold on. I'm just curious about because swift can declare weak on both stored property and normal variables, so there are 2x2 situations for different combination.